# Xcode 7 IPA file size increases by 65MB after apple review

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect, ios9

We have recently published a xcode(7.0.1) / unity3d (4.6.8) build with bitcode off & excluding symbols.

Result in itunesconnect shows 165 MB compressed file size 

After app store review it has 230 MB in the store - very strange.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why don't you ask Apple?

Comment: Since a while ago there's this "Calculate App Store Size" button in Xcode's archive window. Does it give you a reasonable estimate (i.e., close to the 230 MB you are getting)?

Answer (score 1):

Apple un-zips the ipa, encrypts the code and re-zips. The encrypted code does not compress so the size in the store is larger.